# java.lang.NullPointerException en un RecyclerView

Tags: android, recyclerview

Me aparece esta advertencia en un `layout` donde carga un `RecyclerView`  dentro del `onCreate` en esta linea especififcamente en ***setLayoutManager***

```
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
```

me genera lo siguiente :

> Method invocation 'setLayoutManager' may produce
>   'java.lang.NullPointerException

Y para solucionar esto me ofrece

```
assert recyclerView != null;
```

primero que nada quisiera saber el por que de la advertencia y si es efectiva la solución. espero sus ideas. Gracias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El error te indica que ese método puede producir la excepción [`java.lang.NullPointerException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/NullPointerException.html).

Esta excepción, tal y como indica la documentación, se produce debido a lo siguiente:

- Llamar la instancia de un método de un objeto nulo.
- Acceder o modificar un campo de un objeto nulo.
- Obtener la longitud  de nulo como si fuera un array.
- Accediendo o modificando las ranuras de nulo como si fuera un array.
- Lanzar null como si fuera un valor Throwable (lanzable sería la traducción literal pero se trata de un tipo de objeto de Java para lanzar excepciones).

Además, las aplicaciones deberían de lanzar instancias de esta clase para indicar otros usos ilegales del objeto nulo.

Por lo tanto, lo que te está indicando es que se puede producir una excepción en tu código en la cual intentes realizar algunas de las acciones anteriores sobre un objeto nulo lo cual podría terminar tu programa.

Para guardarte las espaldas y que esto no pase, te ofrece una solución. Esto es para que protejas tu código y no se produzcan excepciones que puedan terminar tu programa. Lo que en realidad quiere decir ese código es que apliques lo siguiente:

```
if(recyclerView != null){
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
}
```

De esta forma, si el `recyclerView` es nulo, no ejecutará el método `setLayoutManager` y, por tanto, no se producirá la excepción `java.lang.NullPointerException` para este caso concreto.

Comment: entiendo, gracias !