# Exception java.lang.NullPointerException con un fichero abierto

Tags: java

Ejecuto un main que me genera un fichero PDF. Ese PDF lo tengo abierto, si intento volver a ejecutar ese main, me da el siguiente error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at bbdd.PDF_Clientes_Tabla.crearPDF(PDF_Clientes_Tabla.java:161)
    at bbdd.Main_PDF_Clientes_Tabla.main(Main_PDF_Clientes_Tabla.java:22)
Java Result: 1
```

¿Cómo se puede controlar esa excepción? ¿Con try-catch? ¿O haría falta examinar si el fichero existe con el método `.exists()`?

Código:

```
public class Main_PDF_Clientes_Tabla {
    /**
     * Main.
     * @param args
     * @throws DocumentException 
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws DocumentException{
        //Almacenamos en un arrayList de clientes llamado "ArrayList<Cliente> clientes"
        //todos los datos de la función "ConexionesPDFTabla.listado_clientes();".
        try{
            ArrayList<Cliente> clientes = ConexionesPDFTabla.listado_clientes();
            PDF_Clientes_Tabla.crearPDF(clientes);
            System.out.println("PDF creado correctamente en el directorio actual.");
        }catch(DocumentException ex){
            ex.getMessage();
        }
    }
}


public static void crearPDF(ArrayList<Cliente> clientes) throws DocumentException{
        //Declaramos un documento como un objecto Document. 
        Document documento = new Document(PageSize.LETTER, 80, 80, 75, 75);
        //writer es declarado como el método utilizado para escribir en el archivo.
        PdfWriter writer = null;

        try{
            //Obtenemos la instancia del archivo a utilizar.
            writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(documento, new FileOutputStream(archivo));
        }catch(FileNotFoundException | DocumentException ex){
            ex.getMessage();
        }

        //Agregamos un título al documento.
        documento.addTitle("ARCHIVO PDF GENERADO DESDE JAVA");

        //Abrimos el documento a editar.
        documento.open();

        try{
            //Obtenemos la instancia de la imagen/logo.
            Image imagen = Image.getInstance("..\\imagenes\\LOGO.png");
            //Alineamos la imagen al centro del documento.
            imagen.setAlignment(Image.ALIGN_CENTER);
            //Agregamos la imagen al documento.
            documento.add(imagen);
        }catch(IOException | DocumentException ex){
            ex.getMessage();
        }

        //Creamos un párrafo nuevo llamado "vacio1" para espaciar los elementos.
        Paragraph vacio1 = new Paragraph();
        vacio1.add("\n\n");
        documento.add(vacio1);

        //Declaramos un texto llamado "titulo" como Paragraph. 
        //Le podemos dar formato alineado, tamaño, color, etc.
        Paragraph titulo = new Paragraph();
        titulo.setAlignment(Paragraph.ALIGN_CENTER);
        titulo.setFont(FontFactory.getFont("Times New Roman", 24, Font.BOLD, BaseColor.RED));
        titulo.add("***LISTADO DE CLIENTES***");

        try{
            //Agregamos el texto "titulo" al documento.
            documento.add(titulo);
        }catch(DocumentException ex){
            ex.getMessage();
        }

        //Creamos un párrafo nuevo llamado "saltolinea1" simulando un salto de linea para espaciar
        //los elementos del PDF.
        Paragraph saltolinea1 = new Paragraph();
        saltolinea1.add("\n\n");
        documento.add(saltolinea1);

        //Añadimos una tabla de 7 columnas. 
        PdfPTable tabla = new PdfPTable(7); 
        //Datos de porcentaje a la tabla (tamaño ancho).
        tabla.setWidthPercentage(120);
        //Datos del ancho de cada columna.
        tabla.setWidths(new float[] {12, 18, 10, 12, 20, 14, 24});

        //Añadimos los títulos a la tabla. 
        Paragraph columna1 = new Paragraph("NOMBRE");
        columna1.getFont().setStyle(Font.BOLD);
        columna1.getFont().setSize(9);
        tabla.addCell(columna1);

        Paragraph columna2 = new Paragraph("APELLIDOS");
        columna2.getFont().setStyle(Font.BOLD);
        columna2.getFont().setSize(9);
        tabla.addCell(columna2);

        Paragraph columna3 = new Paragraph("DNI");
        columna3.getFont().setStyle(Font.BOLD);
        columna3.getFont().setSize(9);
        tabla.addCell(columna3);

        Paragraph columna4 = new Paragraph("TELÉFONO");
        columna4.getFont().setStyle(Font.BOLD);
        columna4.getFont().setSize(9);
        tabla.addCell(columna4);

        Paragraph columna5 = new Paragraph("DIRECCION");
        columna5.getFont().setStyle(Font.BOLD);
        columna5.getFont().setSize(9);
        tabla.addCell(columna5);

        Paragraph columna6 = new Paragraph("CIUDAD");
        columna6.getFont().setStyle(Font.BOLD);
        columna6.getFont().setSize(9);
        tabla.addCell(columna6);

        Paragraph columna7 = new Paragraph("EMAIL");
        columna7.getFont().setStyle(Font.BOLD);
        columna7.getFont().setSize(9);
        tabla.addCell(columna7);

        //Recorremos cada arrayList e imprimimos los resultados. 
        for (int i = 0; i<clientes.size(); i++){ 
            columna1 = new Paragraph(clientes.get(i).getNombre());
            columna1.getFont().setSize(7);
            tabla.addCell(columna1);

            columna2 = new Paragraph(clientes.get(i).getApellidos());
            columna2.getFont().setSize(7);
            tabla.addCell(columna2);

            columna3 = new Paragraph(clientes.get(i).getDNI());
            columna3.getFont().setSize(7);
            tabla.addCell(columna3);

            columna4 = new Paragraph(clientes.get(i).getTlf_contacto());
            columna4.getFont().setSize(7);
            tabla.addCell(columna4);

            columna5 = new Paragraph(clientes.get(i).getDireccion());
            columna5.getFont().setSize(7);
            tabla.addCell(columna5);

            columna6 = new Paragraph(clientes.get(i).getCiudad());
            columna6.getFont().setSize(7);
            tabla.addCell(columna6);

            columna7 = new Paragraph(clientes.get(i).getEmail());
            columna7.getFont().setSize(7);
            tabla.addCell(columna7);
        } 

        //Añadimos la tabla "tabla" al documento "documento".
        documento.add(tabla);   
        //Cerramos el documento.
        documento.close();
        //Cerramos el writer.
        writer.close();
    }
```

Comment: ¿Puedes mostrar el método crearPDF?

Comment: Relacionada: http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/41575/java-lang-nullpointerexception-en-un-recyclerview/41579#41579

Comment: Deberías de agregar también cual es la línea que hace referencia a la línea 161.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tienes 2 opciones:

1. Controlar la excepción con un catch adicional generico para que no dé error:

```
try {
    //Obtenemos la instancia del archivo a utilizar.
    writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(documento, new FileOutputStream(archivo));
} catch(FileNotFoundException | DocumentException ex) {
    ex.getMessage();
} catch(Exception ex) {
    ex.getMessage();
}
```

2. Comprobar si el fichero existe y cambiarle el nombre si fuera el caso:

```
try {
    //Si el fichero existe generamos otro nombre
    String nombre = archivo;
    int counter = 1;
    while(new File(nombre).exists()) {
        //Está linea de código obviamente no funcionaría ya que habría que tener en cuenta la extensión
        nombre = archivo + counter.toString();
        counter++;
    }
    //Obtenemos la instancia del archivo a utilizar.
    writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(documento, new FileOutputStream(nombre));
} catch(FileNotFoundException | DocumentException ex) {
    ex.getMessage();
}
```

Puedes tambien combinar las 2 opciones

Answer (score 1):

Si tienes abierto el pdf con otro programa no podrás cerrar el writer ni guardar los cambios, te pasara lo mismo si lo abres con 2 programas a la vez y intentas guardarlo.

Puedes mostrar un mensaje en caso de que este abierto por otro programa o realizar X acción, comprobándolo así:

```
//archivo=nombre del pdf
//Intentaremos guardar una copia del mismo fichero que tenemos para comprobar si nos deja guardarlo, si no nos deja es que esta abierto por otro programa
 File file = new File(archivo);

    File sameFileName = new File(archivo);
    if(file.renameTo(sameFileName)){
        // 
        System.out.println("El fichero no esta pillado por ningún programa, podemos guardar los cambios");  
        writer.close(); 
    }else{
        // El fichero esta abierto, mostrar mensaje para avisar al usuario de ello o realizar X acción
        System.out.println("El fichero esta abierto por otro programa");

    }
```